# где определен пункт меню?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++

VC++ 2002.

один пункт меню(ставится галочка) отвечает за открытие и закрытие некоторого окна.

Мне надо узнать-открыто или закрыто окно.
Для этого я хочу сделать флажок, который устанавливается в 1 при открытии и в 0 при закрытии.

но я не знаю, где в программе описано открытие и закрытие  этого окна. Помогите найти,пожалуйста?) Где ассоциируется пункт меню с его кодом?

Comment: Помогите для начала себе сами: покажите нам Ваш исходный код :)

Comment: @mega, я бы с радостью. но дело в том, что файл, ,,отвечающий,, за окна имеет 4543 строки. мне кажется вряд ли кто то будет в этом разбираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через define должна быть определена константа, отвечающая за определённый пункт меню. Например:

```
#define ID_TITLE 40008
```

В файле ресурсов(расширение *.rc) должно быть описано само меню, и должно быть указано: какому пункту меню соответствует какая константа. Примерно так:

```
BEGIN
   POPUP "Wo&rk"
    BEGIN
      MENUITEM "Сменить Заголовок",           ID_TITLE    
    END 
END
```

В функции обработки событий(WindowProcedure) должен быть код обработки нажатия пункта меню по сообщению WM_COMMAND:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case ID_TITLE:
        /* код смены заголовка*/
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> я бы с радостью. но дело в том, что файл, ,,отвечающий,, за окна имеет 4543 строки. мне кажется вряд ли кто то будет в этом разбираться

Ну, смотрите тогда на код сообщений `WM_NCCREATE/WM_CREATE` - создание окна и `WM_NCDESTROY/WM_DESTROY` - уничтожение окна. А пункт меню ассоциируется с кодом на сообщении `WM_COMMAND`.